# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined - input being read incorrectly

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Not sure how to get the id of my target because it keeps reading it as undefined. I may have set up my argument incorrectly but I'm fairly sure that's not the issue. My command to kick is `!o kick @user kick reason` if that helps.

```
const { message } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'This command kicks a member',
        execute(message, args){
            if (message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS"])) {
            const target = message.mentions.members.first();
            if(target){
                let [target, ...reasonKick] = args;
                [...reasonKick].join(' ');
                message.guild.members.cache.find(target => target.id)
                const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
                if (message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {

                if (message.author.id === memberTarget) {
                    message.reply('why would you want to kick yourself?');
                }
                else if (message.client.user.id === memberTarget) {
                    message.channel.send('Nice try, but you can\'t kick me.')
                }
                else if (message.member.roles.highest.position > message.guild.members.cache.get(memberTarget).roles.highest.position) {
                    memberTarget.kick()
                    message.channel.send(`**${target.tag}** has been kicked. Reason: **${reasonKick}**.`);
                    }
                else {
                    message.reply(`I don\'t have the required permission to kick **${target.tag}**`);
                        }
                    } else {
                        message.reply('I don\'t have the required permission to kick members');
                    }
            } else{
                message.reply('you must mention the member you want to kick.')
                  .catch;
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("you do not have the permission to do that.")
              .catch;
            }
    },
};
// - someCollection.find('property', value);
// + someCollection.find(element => element.property === value)
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: Are you passing the `message` variable correctly?

Comment: @toasty, I'm calling it in my main.js file.

Comment: Can you show me / us how you're calling this function? And why are requiring `message` from `discord.js`? This could create a conflict because you are also using `message` as a variable for your function

Comment: @j-petty Mentions return a Discord collection which extends map, `[0]` would not work unless you call `.array()` on the collection.

Comment: @Elitezen, should I just stick with mention then?

Comment: `message.author.id === memberTarget` is invalid, an entire member object will never equal a string id

Comment: Also, `catch` is a callback, not a property. It must be called with a parameter or another high order function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mention already returns a member object, theres no need to try and get a member based on the mention's id.

Replace all of your `memberTarget`, with `target`

Comment: This is my code now but when I run it, I'm getting no output
`if (message.member.hasPermission(["KICK_MEMBERS"])) {
            // const target = message.mentions.members.first();
            let [target, ...reasonKick] = args;
                [...reasonKick].join(' ');
            if(target){
                message.guild.members.cache.find(target => target.id);
                if (message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {`

Comment: 1) I recommend using `...member.permissions.has()` instead of `.hasPermissions()`, as I believe it's soon to be deprecated. 2) `.find(target => target.id)` ???. There are alot of checks in your code. It's your job to debug and see which are/are not returning true